# How to increase the width of a chip in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to increase the width of `Chip()`. How can I achieve this?

```
Chip(                                       
  elevation: 6.0,                                      
  backgroundColor:  Colors.white,                                          
  shape: 
   RoundedRectangleBorder(                                            
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)                                          ),                                          
   label: Text('09AM - 10AM'),                                 
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `padding` property:

```
Chip(                                       
  elevation: 6.0,                                      
  backgroundColor:  Colors.white, 
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left :20, right : 20),
  shape: 
   RoundedRectangleBorder(                                            
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),                                          
   label: Text('09AM - 10AM'),                                 
),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip/padding.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html