# How to increase width of ChoiceChip to same value for all?

Tags: flutter, android-chips

I am using https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ChoiceChip-class.html and I want to make them same size.

I found out this solution [How to increase the width of a chip in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808665/how-to-increase-the-width-of-a-chip-in-flutter) but padding is not solution because then width depends on text size so I am getting different width for every ChoiceChip.

I also tried with wrapping it with Container but this also didnt work for me.

```
ChoiceChip(
     label: AutoSizeText(local.searchNoLocation),
     selected: helperSelected == 3,
     selectedColor: Color(0xffffcfcf),
     labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: helperSelected == 3 ? Colors.red[300] : Colors.black),
     onSelected: (_) {
        setState(() => helperSelected = 3);
     })
```

Comment: did you try to give "width" to container? Container(width:100,child:ChoiceChip(......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]Just wrap the label property with any widget that you can control with its width and height like Container or SizedBox

```
  ChoiceChip(
            label: Container(
                width: 50,
                child: Text("searchNoLocation",overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)),
            selected: helperSelected == 3,
            selectedColor: Color(0xffffcfcf),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: helperSelected == 3 ? Colors.red[300] : Colors.black),
            onSelected: (_) {
              setState(() => helperSelected = 3);
            }),
        ChoiceChip(
            label: Container(
                width: 250,
                height: 40,
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                child: Text("searchNoLocation",overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)),
            selected: helperSelected == 3,
            selectedColor: Color(0xffffcfcf),
            labelStyle: [![TextStyle][1]][1](
                color: helperSelected == 3 ? Colors.red[300] : Colors.black),
            onSelected: (_) {
              setState(() => helperSelected = 3);
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

For making them actually the same size you need the label to have the same size. If you want them inside a `Row` or `Column` and using the same amount of space in the mainAxis, you can wrap them inside an `Expanded` widget.

```dart
Row(
  children: const [
    Expanded(
      child: ChoiceChip(
        selected: false,
        label: Text('Bigger Text'),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ChoiceChip(
        selected: false,
        label: Text('Text'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to increase the width and height of the choice chip is using of padding property in flutter.

padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10,right:10,top:10,bottom:10)

According to the design we can add like this.